# Should I point out the offering for my company when negotiating a raise?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I know the title may seem confusing, but I was hired to my current company out of college at a "post-college" rate for my job title (read: less then the minimum for what they pay).  Ever since then, I've been behind the base-pay for my job title according to my company's salary calculator, with only this year catching up to what I should be paid minimum.  I just learned of an upcoming promotion, and I'll probably hear the details about it in an hour or so.  I'm afraid though that they will set my salary below the minimum again (it's only been 3 years since I graduated).

If this happens, should I bring up the salary calculator saying what my minimum should be?  I love my job, and my bosses, I just want to be recognized and compensated AT LEAST what my title reflects, but I don't want to cause bad blood.  I know I will negotiate my worth to the company first, but I just don't know if this should be in the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm afraid though that they will set my salary below the minimum again
>
> If this happens, should I bring up the salary calculator saying what
> my minimum should be?

Sure. It probably couldn't hurt.

But it would be surprising if they don't know your salary and the salary levels for the position. So you won't be telling them something they don't already know.

You would be better served negotiating for a raise based on your value to the company.

Before you meet, remind yourself of all the good things you have done for the company the past 3 years, and think about why you will be worth more to the company than "the minimum" after you are promoted.

Express those thoughts in your meeting and ask for more.  If it were me, I'd lead with the "value to company" idea when negotiating a new salary. But if that failed, then ask why you are below the "minimum" for the new position (if it actually turns out that way).

If I had to guess, you won't be below the minimum if you do get the promotion.

Comment: Oh, of course!  I realize my post came across as I was only going to say "Well, the minimum is...".  I was just wondering if I shouls bring it up at all should all else fail, or if that would be too...much?